# Kylo service startup fails

Tags: hadoop, kylo

I try to install Kylo on my existing HDP 2.6.2 Hadoop cluster. I follow [Kylo Document](https://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/v0.8.3/installation/HDP25ClusterDeploymentGuide.html#) but when I try to start Kylo, it says starting, but start fails a few seconds later and status turns stopped.

```
[root@<KYLO_EDGE_NODE> ~]# service kylo-services start
Starting kylo-services ...
using NiFi profile: nifi-v1.2
[root@<KYLO_EDGE_NODE> ~]# service kylo-services status
Running. Here are the related processes:
29294 java
[root@<KYLO_EDGE_NODE> ~]# service kylo-services status
Running. Here are the related processes:
29294 java
[root@<KYLO_EDGE_NODE> ~]# service kylo-services status
Stopped.
```

I share important part of Kylo service logs due to restriction.

```
    2017-10-23 17:34:58 INFO  main:KyloVersionUtil:100 - finding version information from /opt/kylo/kylo-services/conf/version.txt 
    2017-10-23 17:34:58 INFO  main:KyloVersionUtil:108 - loaded Kylo version file: 0.8.3.3  build Time: 2017-10-16 16:17
    2017-10-23 17:35:00 ERROR main:ConnectionPool:182 - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
    java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'kylo'@'<KYLO_EDGE_NODE>' (using password: YES)
    2017-10-23 17:35:01 ERROR main:ConnectionPool:182 - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
    java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'kylo'@'<KYLO_EDGE_NODE>' (using password: YES)
2017-10-23 17:35:16 ERROR localhost-startStop-1:TomcatStarter:63 - Error starting Tomcat context: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
```

on mysql instance, kylo database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'kylo'@'<KYLO_EDGE_NODE>' IDENTIFIED BY '%password%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

didn't work.

I can reach mysql instance with:`mysql -u kylo -p`

Comment: Can you show us full stack trace please, there seems to be some unsatisfied spring dependency which is not shown here.

Comment: I can't put all logs here but I put extensive logs on my blog. Please refer http://www.datascience.istanbul/2017/10/24/kylo-startup-error-code/

Comment: Here is your error: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ‘kylo’@” (using password: YES)
Check your settings in /opt/kylo/kylo-services/conf/application.properties with regard database settings

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<MYSQL_INSTANCE_NODE>:3306/kylo?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true
spring.datasource.username=kylo
spring.datasource.password=password

Comment: properties file seems ok. I have checked many times but could't find sth worng, to my opinion ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the MySQL user you've configured in Kylo does not exist in the MySQL server. Please ensure that you've created a user in MySQL with the same username as Kylo's `spring.datasource.username`, same password as `spring.datasource.password`, and the same host as `<KYLO_EDGE_NODE>`.

You can verify the MySQL user is created properly by running MySQL from the command-line on the Kylo server:

```
mysql -u kylo -p <MYSQL_INSTANCE_NODE> kylo
```

Additionally, you can download the MySQL JDBC driver and install the jar file to `/opt/kylo/kylo-services/lib/` then delete the `/opt/kylo/kylo-services/lib/mariadb-java-client-1.5.7.jar` file from Kylo.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I did all. But by new settings, I encounter new ERRORS :) First I realized schema wasn't completely created. I dropped all tables and recreated. I used suggested script, `generate-update-sql.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found fundamental solution. I removed kylo and activemq, then freshly installed again with rpm. I don't know what I have done different? But, now It works, I can login and kylo-services starts and doesn't stop.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one, It worked for me

The above syntax is incorrect

drop the created user, then run below query

```html
CREATE USER 'kylo'@'<KYLO_EDGE_NODE>' IDENTIFIED BY IDENTIFIED BY '%password%'; 

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'kylo'@'<KYLO_EDGE_NODE>' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

And restart the mysql server

then start the kylo-service